# table rows are showing invulnerable behavior on ng-repeat with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with last column header having two buttons block and unblock  from which only one should be visible based on `ng-show`.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="detail in details| startFrom:(currentDetailPage-1)* pageSize|limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
                    <tr>                <!--<td>{{detail.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{detail.gender}}</td>
                        <td>{{detail.mobileNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{detail.emailId}}</td>
                        <td>{{detail.defvpa}}</td>-->

                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.user_name}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.mobile_no}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.email_id}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.default_vpa}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.def_vpa_name}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">{{detail.last_trans_ctr}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="blockUserDetailCls">
                                <!--<div class="b1">-->
                                <div class="b1" ng-show="showUserUnblockBtn">
                                    <button ng-click="unblockUser($index);">Unblock</button>
                                    <!--<span class="b1tooltip">Blocked</span>-->
                                </div>
                                <!--<div class="b2">-->
                                <div class="b2" ng-show="showUserBlockBtn">
                                    <button ng-click="blockUser($index);">Block</button>
                                    <!--<span class="b2tooltip">Not Blocked</span>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

    </tbody>
```

I have to show one of these buttons based on sever response.

```
for(var j=0; j<=response.data.users.length-1; j++){
                                if(response.data.users[j].block != undefined){
                                    if(response.data.users[j].block == 1){
                                        console.log("blockTrue");
                                        $scope.showUserUnblockBtn = true;
                                        $scope.showUserBlockBtn = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log("blockFalse");
                                    $scope.showUserUnblockBtn = false;
                                    $scope.showUserBlockBtn = true;
                                }
                             }
```

Result is not meeting with my requirement. As if first rows is true for any of these case then all rows show the same result.

Comment: please add a speaking title!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same scope variables for each user. You need to use an array or you can
use condition on your ng-show, something like below:

```
<td>
     <div class="blockUserDetailCls">
     <!--<div class="b1">-->
     <div class="b1" ng-show="detail.block==1">
      <button ng-click="unblockUser($index);"><i class="fas fa-user-slash"></i></button>
       <!--<span class="b1tooltip">Blocked</span>-->
        </div>
        <!--<div class="b2">-->
        <div class="b2" ng-show="detail.block!=1">
        <button ng-click="blockUser($index);"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></button>
        <!--<span class="b2tooltip">Not Blocked</span>-->
         </div>
        </div>
</td>
```

assuming you are filling the details array in a for loop this is a possible way to fix the issue:

```
$scope.details=[];
for(var j=0; j<=response.data.users.length-1; j++)
{
    var det={
             user_name: response.data.users[j].user_name,
             mobile_no: response.data.users[j].mobile_no,
             email_id: response.data.users[j].email_id,
             default_vpa: response.data.users[j].default_vpa,
             def_vpa_name: response.data.users[j].default_vpa_name,
             last_trans_ctr: response.data.users[j].last_trans_ctr,
             block: response.data.users[j].block  //this is the line that will be used in ng-show

           };
    $scope.details.push(det);
}
```

Comment: @sumitkumar add block property in the items of details array

Comment: i dont know how to do this. please suggest code for js as well as view

Comment: add the details array structure please

Comment: i bring data into the details array on server response as `$scope.details = response.data.users` on response as `response.data.user[pos].block ==1`, I have to make visible block button else unblock button will visible.

Comment: If you want to get a good answer add the js code that fill up the details array please